# Ceiling and floor functions in Java

Tags: java

Why do Math.ceil() and Math.floor() functions return **double** in Java? Where as their outputs are actually integers! Isn't it an over generalization to make all functions return double? How is it good to be so, if it is at all?

Comment: Probably because of the much wider range that double provides.

Answer (score 2):

It returns `double` to handle numbers larger than the range of `long`. If it returned `long` then it could not return a correct value if the input value exceeded the max possible `long`